# How could one have typewriter (monospaced) numbers throughout a document (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, luatex, typewriter

- I would like to have **all numbers** in a **typewriter** (monospace) **font** throughout my document, but maintain the usual serif font for everything else.
- See **column A** in the **picture below** (which was kindly provided by user **egreg**.)
- How could I achieve this?
- I want to use using **LuaLaTeX**.
- Currently, I am not using the `fontspec` package and I am utilizing the default `\rmfamily` as my main font.

[image]

Comment: Your objective isn't clear. In the title, you employ the term **monospaced**, but in the body of the posting you use the term **teletyped**. These terms are *not* synonyms. While it's true that "teletype" numerals all take up the same width (indeed, the same width as all other printable characters do) and hence can be called "monospaced", the converse is not true. Numerals can either take up the same amount of space ("fixed width") or be proportionately spaced. This is true regardless of whether the numerals are uppercase/lining or lowercase/oldstyle. In short, please clarify your objective.

Comment: Please indicate (a) whether you use the `fontspec` package and (b) which text font you employ at present.

Comment: @Mico Your comment on the difference between the terms _monospaced_ and _teletyped_ (I do not know the latter term) is not clear to me. You mention that both have fixed width glyphs but then talk about proportional spacing. What would be an example of a font / numerals that are one but not the other?

Comment: @schtandard - In a teletype font face, the 10 arabic numerals all occupy the same width (as do all other glyphs of the font face). But teletype-font numerals aren't the *only* monospaced numerals. Take the (standard) numerals of either Computer Modern Roman or Computer Modern Sans: They, too, occupy the exact same widths. The OP says that he/she uses LuaLaTeX but, surprisingly (to me at least) doesn't use the `fontspec` package. That's too bad, as running `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{<SetDesiredFontHere>}[Numbers=Monospaced]` would *assure* the use of monospaced numerals.

Comment: @schtandard - To continue my previous example: Let's assume a font face provides both lining numbers and oldstyle numbers, both fixed-width (aka monospaced) and variable-width (aka proportionately spaced). (Quite a few OpenType fonts do.) The `fontspec` option combinations `Numbers=[Proportional,Oldstyle]`, `Numbers=[Proportional,Lining]`, `Numbers=[Monospaced,Oldstyle]`, `Numbers=[Monospaced,Lining]` let you keep track separately of the *style* (Oldstyle vs. Lining)  and *spacing* (Proportional vs. Monospaced) of the numerals.

Comment: @Mico So you're saying that `fontspec` is all I need? I have no issue adopting the use of a package, if it doesn't clutter up my source files, if it doesn't have many incompatibilities with many common packages or increase compiltation times a lot.

Comment: @SeSodesa - As you probably already know, users of LuaLaTeX (and, for that matter, XeLaTeX too) should *not* load the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages; that's independent of whether or not the `fontspec` package is loaded. If LuaLaTeX users do *not* load the `fontspec` package, they get the Computer Modern text font (and the Latin Modern math font) by default. In contrast, if they load `fontspec`, they get Latin Modern as the text font.

Comment: @SeSodesa - The very first time a LuaLaTeX document that uses `fontspec` loads an OpenType font, the compilation is slowed because the `luaotfload` utility has to create a hash file. This slowdown should be a one-time-only event, in the sense that subsequent compilations that use this font will get ready access to the hash file.

Comment: @SeSodesa Please specify whether you want column A or column B in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXGTi.png)

Comment: @Mico What is unclear to me is what property of a font makes it "teletype". For monospaced fonts, this is obvious: All characters occupy the same width. As you seem to say that this does not make any monospaced font also a teletype font, what is the essential characteristic of a teletype font? (After searching online I'm not sure there is a clear definition. It seems to be used mainly to describe a certain aesthetic, like "typewriter".) As the OP decided on "teletyped" instead of "monospaced", will simply selecting `Numbers=Monospaced` actually give the desired result?

Comment: @schtandard - My apologies for not being sufficiently clear in the distinctions I made. Let me try again. (a) All teletype font faces are monospaced; in particular, the glyphs of the arabic numerals subset take up the same space. (b) For a non-teletype font face, it does *not* follow that its numerals are necessarily *not monospaced*. Indeed, for font faces such as CM Roman and CM Sans, their numerals are monospaced by default.

Comment: @Mico Ah, I see what you wanted to say now.

Comment: @egreg Column A.

Comment: @Mico That's for you, then! :-)

Comment: @egreg - Do you approve of (or, more realistically, not roll your eyes at) the answer I just posted? :-)

Comment: @Mico I think that the idea is on the verge of perversion…

Comment: @egreg I took the liberty to add your picture to the question (and prettify together with the picture addition).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution which works with and without the `fontspec` package.

The solution consists of (a) a Lua function called `ttnumbers`, which uses Lua's powerful `string.gsub` function to encase all instances of numerals found in the input stream in `\texttt` directives, and (b) two utility Latex macros, called `\ttnumbersOn` and `\ttnumbersOff`, which activate and deactivate the `ttnumbers` function. Note that the action of the `\ttnumbersOn` and `\ttnumbersOff` directives takes effect not on the line where the respective macros are encountered, but only on the *next* line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luaexec" macro
\luaexec{ %% Set up the Lua function:
   function ttnumbers ( s )
      return ( s:gsub ( "\%d+" , "\\texttt{\%0}" ) )
   end
}
\newcommand\ttnumbersOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", ttnumbers , "ttnumbers" )}}
\newcommand\ttnumbersOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", "ttnumbers" )}}

\begin{document}
%% roman text font
1234567890 vs.\ 
\ttnumbersOn 
1234567890 
\ttnumbersOff

% math font
$1234567890$ vs.\
\ttnumbersOn
$1234567890$
\ttnumbersOff

% sans-serif text font
\sffamily
1234567890 vs.\ 
\ttnumbersOn 
1234567890
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to break any calls to `\input{<filename with number>}` with an error `Missing \endcsname inserted.`. For example, `\input{01-introduction.tex}` becomes `\input{\texttt{01}-introduction.tex}`, which LuaLaTeX seems to dislike.

Comment: @SeSodesa — You’re absolutely correct — and I’m entirely unapologetic. Indeed, I’m certain that there are *many* other circumstances where this approach will also misfire. That’s precisely why I provided the `\ttnumbersOff` macro as well — to let you suspend operation of the Lua function. Since you provided exactly zero background as to how you might use the numerals-substitution procedure, I’m simply in no position to provide something more robust.

Comment: That is fair. I might ask another question later on how this might be improved to facilitate the use of the mentioned `\input` calls and citations. This approach does break pretty much every feature useful in writing articles or theses, after all, as it is unnecessarily difficult to avoid inserting numbers into your `.bib` file, for example, if you wish to differentiate between two different articles from the same author.

Comment: @SeSodesa - Thanks for the accept vote. :-) I must confess that I simply don't understand the entire premise of your query. The numerals of the Computer Modern and Latin Modern serif and sans-serif fonts *are* monospaced -- why not declare victory right there and then? :-) LaTeX and TeX are supposed to enable creating of fine typography. Unquestionably, mixing-and-mismatching roman and teletype glyphs is pretty much the *antithesis* of fine typesetting.

Answer (score 12):

With lualatex you can setup  combo fonts. But imho this is rather bad typography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{combofont}
\setupcombofont{ttnumber-regular}
 {
  {file:lmroman10-regular.otf:\combodefaultfeat} at #1pt,
  {file:lmmono10-regular.otf:mode=node;} at #1pt
 }
 {
  {},
  0x30-0x39
 }

\setupcombofont{ttnumber-bold}
 {
  {file:lmroman10-bold.otf:\combodefaultfeat} at #1pt,
  {file:lmmonolt10-bold:mode=node; } at #1pt
 }
 {
  {},
  0x30-0x39
 }

\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{ttnumber}{}
\DeclareFontShape {TU}{ttnumber}{m}{n} {<->combo*ttnumber-regular}{}
\DeclareFontShape {TU}{ttnumber}{b}{n}{<->combo*ttnumber-bold}{} 
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ttnumber}
\begin{document}
some text 1234567890 \bfseries some text 1234567890


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this package! I had similar problems to solve in the past and it was mostly a rather difficult approach compared to this.

Answer (score 6):

With ConTeXt this can be achieved with the font fallback mechanism where you can replace certain letters with letters from another font.

```
\definefallbackfamily [teletypenumbers] [rm] [Latin Modern Typewriter]
  [range=digitsnormal,
   force=yes]

\definefontfamily [teletypenumbers] [rm] [Latin Modern Roman]

\setupbodyfont[10pt]

\starttext

Number test: 0123456789

\setupbodyfont [teletypenumbers]

Number test: 0123456789

\stoptext
```

[image]